# Overlapping while replacing one fragment with another

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have been trying to replace the fragment with another fragment if user clicks on one of the list item. Now the problem is the other fragment is getting displayed but it is not replacing previous frame but it is just getting displayed on top of the previous fragment. This is how I am calling my new fragment on list item click:

```
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String sender = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sender)).getText() .toString();
            String subject = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject)).getText() .toString();
            String fname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.file_name)).getText() .toString();


            Fragment frag =new  DisplayFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("file_name", fname);
             frag.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, frag);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and activity associated with this fragment is:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

now the code for new fragment is:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_displayfile, container, false);
    return rootView;

}
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String myfile = (String)bundle.get("file_name");        
    tv.setText(myfile);
}
```

and its associated activity is :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/display_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

the desired output should be the textview in new fragment should replace whole content of previous fragment. but the output after clicking item that I am getting is:
[image]
this "hi" should get displayed alone not with the list. It seems my code is correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue here is that you have a frame layout n a list view in a single view. You are replacing your frame with the fragment but your list view is still there.

1. Use fragment in your xml instead of frame layout and list view
2. Create a list fragment
3. On create of activity add list fragment to the view
4. On list item click replace list fragment with your fragment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No placing the listview inside frame layout isnt helping

Comment: One option  is to replace frame layout that I understood but what is "use list view id in fragment replacement" how do you do that?

Comment: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.list, frag);

Comment: No if I do that I am getting exception

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:addView(View) is not supported in adapterView

Comment: I am trying to do what you have suggested but not able to get the desired result. I guess I am not doing it correctly can you just show me code wise if possible ? I am sorry very new to android.

Comment: @SubodhMankar please see and get the idea from this article [Fragment Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: I have understood that tutorial and trying to follow it but I am getting null pointer exception on fragment.setText(link); I guess it is not able to find that fragment though I have declared it in xml file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47316/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-subodh-mankar)